# onclick function is not calling the popup form and there is no error

Tags: javascript, html, electron, onclick, popup

iam creating a small electron desktop popup form. So whenever running the program the initial logo is appearing in the desktop and when logo is clicked then onclick function  will deliver the popup form. but whenever iam clicking the button below the logo as designed, form is not loading or no error has been thrown.

```
main.js

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let iconWin = null
let formWin = null

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  iconWin = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 100,
    height: 150,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  })



  iconWin.loadFile('icon.html')
})

function showForm() {

  console.log('showForm called')

  if (formWin) {
    formWin.show()
  } else {
    formWin = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1000,
      height: 1000,
      useContentSize: true,
      maximizable: false,
      minimizable: false,
      resizable: false,
      alwaysOnTop: true,
      frame: false,
      transparent: true,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    })
    formWin.loadFile('form.html')
    formWin.webContents.openDevTools()
    formWin.on('closed', () => {
      formWin = null
    })
  }
}


module.exports = { showForm }




icon.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="icon.png" alt="Icon" />
    <button onclick="showForm()">mrsupport</button>
    
    <script>
      const { remote } = require('electron')
      const showForm = remote.require('./main.js').showForm
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



form.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      form {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      h2 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      input[type="text"],
      textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      input[type="submit"] {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
        <img src="imh.png" alt="Icon" />
      <h2>Mr Support</h2>
      <label for="textfield">Employee ID:</label>
      <input type="text" id="empid" name="empid" required placeholder="Enter your Employee ID"/>
      <label for="textarea">IT Issue:</label>
      <textarea id="issue" name="issue" required placeholder="State your issue facing related to IT"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
      const { remote } = require('electron')
      const currentWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow()

      document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        currentWindow.hide()
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Electron's documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model) on its process model: Your `remote.require('./main.js')` is not a good idea. On the other hand, the code you've provided doesn't register an `onclick` handler for the logo's `img` element, thus `showForm()` cannot be called when clicking the image.

Comment: Iam new to the electron js. Can you suggest me any other method

Comment: Well, then the docs, specifically [the tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-prerequisites), may be helpful.